# I can't perform a squat without falling

Tags: squats, flexibility, mobility

I am unable to perform a squat with both feet flat on the ground.

Here is a picture of the **maximum** depth I achieve without falling (while holding the table).

[image]

I wonder if it is a problem of ankle mobility, because my feet have a very high arch and in the picture I can't put my knees farther in front of me.

Or if it is a problem with the strength or flexibility of my hamstrings?
When I go down I feel that they are very solicited.

- Will it be possible for me to perform a full squat one day?
- Do you have some advice for me to improve my range of motion without falling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"place your foot several inches from a wall. Now, try to move your knee forward until it touches the wall. If your big toe is 4-5 inches from the wall and your knee can’t reach the wall then your ankles are not mobile."
http://blueprintfitnessatlanta.com/squats-why-you-cant-do-them-why-you-should-how-to-fix-it/
for improving your ankle mobility
get a band and wrap it around a solid post and move your foot as far away from the post as possible, repeat on other foot.

Comment: Great advice on how to identify inflexibility. I would add that to develop flexibility: Third World Squats. http://thirdworldsquats.com/

Comment: +1 for third world squats. I know it as the Slav-squat, because you see this in a lot of the Slavic countries, but it's the same thing, and it's surprisingly comfortable and (for me) back-pain alleviating.